# tkz-euclide intercept line and circle

Tags: tkz-euclide

I know its not a full MWE but can anybody explain why I can get the intercept on AC but not on BC

```
\newcommand{\AB}{0.7}   % A  and B added <<<<<<<<<<<<<<
\newcommand{\C}{1.0}    % C added <<<<<<<<<<<<<<
\newcommand{\Asize}{0.25}   % Angle added <<<<<<<<<<<<<<
\newcommand{\AD}{0.75}
\newcommand{\AG}{1.5}


\begin{diagram}
 \tkzDefPoints{-\AB/0/A,\AB/0/B,0/\C/C}

    \tkzDrawSegment(A,C)
    \tkzDrawSegment(B,C)
    
    \tkzLabelPoints[left](A)
    \tkzLabelPoints[right](B)
    \tkzLabelPoints[above](C)
%Get intercect points 

\tkzDefMidPoint(A,C)     \tkzGetPoint{M}
\tkzDrawCircle(C,M)
\tkzInterLC(C,A)(C,M) \tkzGetPoint{D} \tkzLabelPoints[left](D)
 \tkzInterLC(B,C)(C,M) \tkzGetPoint{E} \tkzLabelPoints[right](E)
\tkzDrawPoints(D,E)
\end{diagram}
```

[image]

Comment: What are the definitions of `\AB`, `\C` and `diagram`?

Comment: Sorry just edited

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the macro `tkzGetPoints`with (s) !! line and circle can have two points in common.

```
\documentclass{standalone} 
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}

\begin{document} 
\begin{tikzpicture}
 \tkzDefPoints{-2/0/A,2/0/B,0/4/C}

    \tkzDrawSegments(A,C B,C)    
    \tkzLabelPoints[left](A)
    \tkzLabelPoints[right](B)
    \tkzLabelPoints[above](C)
%Get intercect points 

\tkzDefMidPoint(A,C)     \tkzGetPoint{M}
\tkzDrawCircle(C,M)
\tkzInterLC(C,A)(C,M) \tkzGetPoints{F}{D}\tkzLabelPoints[left](D)
 \tkzInterLC(B,C)(C,M) \tkzGetPoints{E}{G} \tkzLabelPoints[right](E)
\tkzDrawPoints(D,E)
\tkzDrawPoints(M)
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```